# Can a class inherit convenience inits even if there is designated inits

Tags: swift, init, swift-extensions, convenience-methods

I've got the following classes:

```
class A {
    
    let age:Int
    
    init(age: Int) {
        self.age = age
    }
}

extension A {
    convenience init?(ageString: String) {
        guard let age = Int(ageString) else { return nil}
        self.init(age: age)
    }
}

class B: A {
    
    private var name = ""
    
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
        super.init(age: 0)
    }
}
```

When I try to run `B(ageString: "1")` I will get an error because that init doesn't exist.

But if `B` doesn't have any init methods and I make `name` public, it won't complain. But that's not what I want.

Is this because `init?(ageString: String) {` is a convenience method, I can't do it non convenience because is created in an extension.

Are not the convenience init method inherited if there are designated methods in `B`?

Answer (score 2):

First of all don't you get an error that `super` is not called in `init(name:)`?

The convenience initializer is only available if you implement (override) `init(age` in B

```
override init(age: Int) {
    super.init(age: age)
}
```

Comment: Yes, sorry I get an error.

So I would have to override all the init methods of `class A` in `B` , that's a bit...annoying

Thanks for the help

Comment: @xarly It's not "annoying". Swift is helping you get initializers right. Believe the compiler.

Comment: I think it's a bit annoying because the only reason I've got a `convenience` init is because is in an extension and I got it in a extension because it uses and object from another module ( in my real case, not in this example ), so I only need to import that module in the extension file.

The class B should not be aware of this, instead B has to override all the methods from A because someone else creates an extension with a `convenience` init of A.

Maybe I'm approaching this from the wrong way...

Answer (score 1):

> Are not the convenience init method inherited if there are designated methods in B?

No. Implementing a designated initializer in a subclass blocks inheritance of initializers from the superclass — unless you explicitly override, in the subclass, *all* the designated initializers of the superclass.